# Filter rows based on the financial year in Pandas Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to filter those rows in `data` where `billingdate` lies in a financial year or creating a new column that will tell in which financial year this date is lying.

In this dictionary: keys are financial year and values are starting and ending date of that financial year

```
FY = {
    "2018-2019": ["20180401", "20190331"],
    "2019-2020": ["20190401", "20200331"],
    "2020-2021": ["20200401", "20210331"],
}
```

I want to check firstly in which financial year the data is lying and then filter those rows which fulfill this criteria.

For example:
if there is date `'20200216'` FY would be `'2019-2020'`
if there is date `'20200416'` FY would be `'2020-2021'`

I tried the below code but need some improvements.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"billingdate": ['20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210316', '20210317', '20210317']})

df['billingdate'] = pd.to_datetime(ser['billingdate'], errors='coerce')
df['financial_year'] = df['billingdate'].map(lambda x: x.year if x.month > 3 else x.year-1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just compute and not map. Lets try code below

```
ser['billingdate'] = pd.to_datetime(ser['billingdate'], errors='coerce')
ser['financial_year'] = ser['billingdate'].map(lambda x: str(x.year) + "-"+str(x.year+1) if x.month > 3 else str(x.year-1) + "-"+str(x.year))




     billingdate financial_year
0   2021-04-16      2021-2022
1   2021-03-16      2020-2021
2   2021-03-16      2020-2021
3   2021-03-16      2020-2021
4   2021-03-16      2020-2021
5   2021-03-16      2020-2021
6   2021-03-16      2020-2021
7   2021-03-16      2020-2021
8   2021-03-16      2020-2021
9   2021-03-16      2020-2021
10  2021-03-16      2020-2021
11  2021-03-16      2020-2021
12  2021-03-16      2020-2021
13  2021-03-16      2020-2021
14  2021-03-16      2020-2021
15  2021-03-16      2020-2021
16  2021-03-16      2020-2021
17  2021-03-16      2020-2021
```

Comment: Thanx for this answer it is working with my logic. As you have answered first I would accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to maintain a separate dict `FY` with `fiscal year` mappings.
Then, pandas has function which allows to have `custom frequencies` for a `Financial Year`.

**Input**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"billingdate": ['20210416', '20210316', '20210317', '20190317']})
df['billingdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['billingdate'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```

**Input DF**

```
    billingdate
0   2021-04-16
1   2021-03-16
2   2021-03-17
3   2019-03-17
```

**Code**

```
fy=df.billingdate.dt.to_period(freq='Q-MAR').dt.qyear
df['financial_year'] = (fy-1).astype(str) + '-' + fy.astype(str)
df
```

**Output**

```
    billingdate financial_year
0   2021-04-16  2021-2022
1   2021-03-16  2020-2021
2   2021-03-17  2020-2021
3   2019-03-17  2018-2019
```

**Explanation**
In above code we are creating custom freq for `FY` stating that the `FY` ends at `Q-MAR` i.e for eg `from 2021.04.01 FY-2021 ends and FY-2022 starts`.

Comment: You code is working fine also you have used a good method and explanation is also very good. I will upvote your answer but accept on the basis of timing.

Comment: nw, all the best!